# How do companies make sure resources created by an employee are not deleted when he is fired in Azure?

Tags: azure, entra-id, subscription

Correct me if I am wrong, but my understanding is that when an Azure account is deleted, all associated resources are also gone. This makes sense because else I would keep being charged for using resources I no longer have access to. However, this would also mean that the company would always have to make sure to move all created resources from that account to another before deleting the account.

My theory is that the resources are associated not with an account, but with the subscription that was used to create the resource, and the subscriptions are created from a special Azure account used by the company for this purpose. But if you were to delete your account you wouldn't have access to the subscription unless deleting the account deleted the subscriptions created with that account.

I can't find information about this in the Azure docs so I wanted to confirm this by asking here.

Answer (score 4):

> when an Azure account is deleted, all associated resources are also gone

This is incorrect.
A lifecycle of an account used to create a resource has no impact on resource lifecycle. You might want to [manage access](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/ready/azure-setup-guide/manage-access) to resources using Azure AD groups.

Azure provides four levels of management.
**Resources < Resource Groups < Subscriptions < Management Groups**
You can assign access permissions on any and each of these levels.

[image: Azure resource management]